# Intellij is it possible to show value of static variables?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Let's say I have the following code:

```
System.out.println(Math.PI);
```

Is there a plugin or some setting where I can hover over `Math.PI` and have IntelliJ tell me the value of the constant?

Comment: I thought it already did this... Otherwise, you can Ctrl+Click on the variable to see the source

Comment: On my mac, I can do this by holding CMD and hovering. On windows, I assume it'd be CTRL+hover?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> on mac) to activate the `quick documentation` action to see a documentation popup for this constant:

[image]

Also you could hover over `PI` with pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>:

[image]

Furthermore, you always can jump to the source code by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Yep, that's it, thank you. For the record, the full name is Quick Documentation.

Comment: Also, (at least on mac, probably ctrl on win?) when you hold the command key down and hover, you get the quick documentation popup - very handy!

Comment: If the value is too long it gets truncated. When using ctrl+shift+i it shows the whole value (see [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40043467/2294031)).
Helpful tips nevertheless.

Answer (score 18):

#### It's much better to use [View Definition](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/viewing-definition.html) feature.

[image]

By hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (if you're OSX user <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) you will see the method, function, constant, variable definition in window popup.

Example with `Objects#equals` method:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what makes this "better". It's more information, maybe. But I'd like to just hover my mouse over a constant in IntelliJ and its value show up as a tooltip, not have to press a hotkey. Pretty sure Eclipse has this feature.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I wrote not only about constants, _you will see the method, function, constant, variable definition in window popup_.

Comment: Although the quick documentation is helpfull, it doesn't show enough details if the constant contains a more complex definition. Using the view definition action I do see all I need. That makes this a much better option for me than the quick documentation. Thanks :-)

Comment: This is great for Ideavim or whatever its called <3

Comment: Its `Ctrl+Shift+I` with an `I`.
(For people like me who thought it's `Ctrl+Shift+L`. The font used to display the keys makes it hard to distinguish between an uppercase i and a lowercase L.)